# beforeFilter function not redirecting in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have implemented following code to run a code on before any action of any controller. However, the `beforeFilter()` function not redirecting to the route I have specified. Instead it takes the user to the location where the user clicked.

```
//My Listener
namespace Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class BeforeControllerListener
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        if (!is_array($controller))
        {
            //not a controller do nothing
            return;
        }
        $controllerObject = $controller[0];
        if (is_object($controllerObject) && method_exists($controllerObject, "beforeFilter"))
        //Set a predefined function to execute Before any controller Executes its any method
        {
            $controllerObject->beforeFilter();
        }
    }
}
//I have registered it already

//My Controller
class LedgerController extends Controller
{        
    public function beforeFilter()
    {   
        $commonFunction = new CommonFunctions();
        $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
        if ($commonFunction->checkFinancialYear($dm) == 0 ) {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Sorry');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('financialyear'));//Here it is not redirecting
        }
    }
}

public function indexAction() {}
```

Please help, What is missing in it.
Thanks Advance

Comment: simply add return statement at `onKernelController` method. `return $controllerObject->beforeFilter();`.

Comment: Please at least try to format your code properly.

Comment: I meant code in your question, so other could understand it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you follow the Symfony suggestions for [setting up before and after filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html), where you perform your functionality within the filter itself, rather than trying to create a `beforeFilter()` function in your controller that is executed.  It will allow you to achieve what you want - the function being called before every controller action - as well as not having to muddy up your controller(s) with additional code.  In your case, you would also want to inject the Symfony session to the filter:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.before_controller_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\BeforeControllerListener
        arguments: ['@session', '@router', '@doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Then you'll create your before listener, which will need the Symony session and routing services, as well as the MongoDB document manager (making that assumption based on your profile).

```
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/BeforeControllerListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use AppBundle\Controller\LedgerController;
use AppBundle\Path\To\Your\CommonFunctions;

class BeforeControllerListener
{
    private $session;
    private $router;
    private $documentManager;
    private $commonFunctions;

    public function __construct(Session $session, Router $router, DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->dm = $dm;
        $this->commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($controller[0] instanceof LedgerController) {
            if ($this->commonFunctions->checkFinancialYear($this->dm) !== 0 ) {
                return;
            }

            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Sorry');
            $redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');

            $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
                return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you are in fact using the Symfony CMF then the Router might actually be `ChainRouter` and your `use` statement for the router would change to `use Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter;`

There are a few additional things here you might want to reconsider - for instance, if the `CommonFunctions` class needs `DocumentManager`, you might just want to make your `CommonFunctions` class a service that injects the `DocumentManager` automatically.  Then in this service you would only have to inject your common functions service instead of the document manager.

Either way what is happening here is that we are checking that we are in the `LedgerController`, then checking whether or not we want to redirect, and if so we overwrite the entire Controller via a callback.  This sets the redirect response to your route and performs the redirect.

If you want this check on every single controller you could simply eliminate the check for `LedgerController`.
.

Comment: ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\BeforeControllerListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session, string given, called in /var/www/edubolderpHarkamalWork/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 944 and defined in /var/www/edubolderpHarkamalWork/src/Edu/AccountBundle/EventListener/BeforeControllerListener.php line 21. I am getting this Error even I have included following Please guide: use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, I surrounded each service with `%` when it should just begin with `@`, so it should be `@session` instead of `%session%`, etc.  Check the .yml I provided, it's updated properly now.  It was looking for a parameter named `%session%` rather than the service itself.

Comment: Hi Jason I am still facing same Error can you please See this: <service id="edu.account.listener" class="Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\BeforeControllerListener">
            <argument>@session@</argument>
            <argument>@router@</argument>
            <argument>@doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager@</argument>
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.controller" method="onKernelController"/>

        </service>

Comment: I am using services.xml instead of services.yml. Currently in my project.
Edu/MyBundle/Resources/Config/services.xml

Comment: Hello, remove the ending @ on each, it only goes at the start

Comment: I have removed. but Still same error.  not getting exact idea why this error encountered even. Session and other Compononts is already included on this file.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading that xml file in your config so the service gets registered at all?

Comment: Yes. I went terminal to check my registered service Like this:
php app/console container:debug  edu.account.listener
So I get following output there:
Service Id       edu.account.listener
Class            Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\BeforeControllerListener
Tags
    - kernel.event_listener          (event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController)
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Required File

Comment: Here's the proper format for services in XML:  <argument type="service" id="session"/> and so on for the other two

Comment: That thing worked. now I am getting another Error. like
Error: Class 'Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\RedirectResponse' not found in /var/www/edubolderpHarkamalWork/src/Edu/AccountBundle/EventListener/BeforeControllerListener.php line 46.

Comment: Should we need to add components for : RedirectResponse()?

Comment: I'll update my answer, you need to add the RedirectResponse class at the top: `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;`

Comment: I have removed the:
  if ($controller[0] instanceof LedgerController) {} 
Block, because I want to call it on each controller of my Bundle:
But now:
$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Sorry, you have to create financial year first from master to make any process in accounts');

$redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');

Saying that: The page isn't redirecting properly
any idea?

Comment: It's because you removed checking that the controller was an instance of the LedgerController.  When you try to redirect to `financialyear`, this listener is still getting called...so it's doing the check once again which will never pass...which means it will try to infinitely redirect to `financialyear`.  What you want to do is put that `financialyear` route in its own controller, and then in this listener, check that you are *not* in that controller.  So like put that route in `FinancialYearController`, and do `if (!$controller[0] instanceof FinancialYearController)`

Comment: Shoul I create a function inside FinancialYearController to write  to check my logic for redirect. And call that function my ilstener?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to create any logic in a controller itself - besides, the listener will get called first before you have a chance to check for the redirect

Comment: Hi Jason unfortunately. I am getting same error:

The page isn't redirecting properly:
 if (!$controller[0] instanceof FinancialYearController) {
            if ($this->commonFunctions->checkFinancialYear($this->dm) !== 0 ) {
                return;
            }

            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Sorry');
            $redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');//Here problem

            $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
                return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
            });
        }
Please guide

Comment: it is redirecting correct but , showing error that 
"The page isn't redirecting properly". Even now route "financialyear". is in there in "FinincialYearController".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102914/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-user3458514).

Answer (score 2):

`$this->redirect()` controller function simply creates an instance of `RedirectResponse`. As with any other response, it needs to be either returned from a controller, or set on an event. Your method is not a controller, therefore you have to set the response on the event.

However, you cannot really set a response on the `FilterControllerEvent` as it is meant to either update the controller, or change it completely (`setController`). You can do it with other events, like the `kernel.request`. However, you won't have access to the controller there.

You might try set a callback with `setController` which would call  your `beforeFilter()`. However, you wouldn't have access to controller arguments, so you won't really be able to call the original controller if beforeFilter didn't return a response.

Finally you might try to throw an exception and handle it with an exception listener.

I don't see why making things this complex if you can simply call your method in the controller:

```
public function myAction()
{
    if ($response = $this->beforeFilter()) {
        return $response;
    }

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Hi. it showing following Error.Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent::setResponse(). which componont i have to include?

Comment: I want a Common function which will execute very first on each controller. So that I have Create a Listener and Calling it on Kernal OnController Event. and Method is executed but it is not redirecting user to the path which I have given in that function. this is my problem

Comment: As i said in my answer, it's not possible to return a response from the filter controller event. You can either do it in your controller, or throw an exception and handle it with an exception listener.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $response = new Response();

    // Matched route
    $_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');

    // Matched controller
    $_controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller');

    $params = array(); //Your params

    $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
    $redirectUrl = $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route,$params);


    $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
         return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    });
}
```

Cheers !!